# Proving a module is projective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module

I read this statement and I have no idea how to prove it:

Every flat module over a PID is projective.

Is this even right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false.  For instance, over the PID $\mathbb{Z}$, the module $\mathbb{Q}$ is flat but not projective.

Answer (score 5):

This is not true, but over [left noetherian rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noetherian_ring) and over [semiperfect rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiperfect_ring), every **finitely generated** flat module is projective.

Answer (score 4):

Eric Wofsey has already cut to the heart of the matter with the example, but here's some more information.

A classic theorem of Bass is that a ring is right perfect iff every left flat module is projective.

But a commutative, perfect domain has to be a field, since perfect rings satisfy the DCC on principal ideals (and nonfield domains do not.)

But every *projective* module over a PID is *free*. That's something that 'rhymes' with what you're saying.